# How to use UIGetScreenImage

Tags: iphone

I would like to be able to do a real time analysis of the image taken by the camera.
I've seen that we are now allowed to use the undocumented UIGetScreenImage function.
However, I do not succeed to use it, I have the following warning:

implicit declaration of function 'UIGetScreenImage'

any idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

regards,

Comment: UIGetScreenImage is not allowed anymore. I've just got an email from Apple asking to stop using this private function and use -renderInContext: (on iOs 3.x) or AV Foundation AVCaptureSession and related classes (on iOS 4).

Comment: I've got the same email. This is a pity, It means to change your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a prototype

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
```

in your source code (or some common headers).

---

Note that you need to `CGImageRelease` the result of `UIGetScreenImage` even it is a "Get" function.