# Is there an alternative to the CALayer -renderInContext: method?

Tags: iphone

I need a way of capturing a view or the screen with *everything* just exactly like it appears on screen. -renderInContext: won't do that. Are there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 1):

Several, but start with:

```
UIGetScreenImage();
```

Which returns a CGImageRef.  If you use this, note that the image is retained, and you should release it.

**Edit**:

Add for completeness the main other way to do this:

```
UIWindow *aWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aWindow.frame.size);
[[aWindow layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: this seems to not be available on iPhone OS

Comment: It is, but you need to add a declaration for the function to remove the warning, and it doesn't work in the simulator.

Comment: @mystify See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213463/how-to-use-uigetscreenimage

Comment: UIGetScreenImage is not allowed anymore. I've just got an email from Apple asking to stop using this private function and use -renderInContext: (on iOs 3.x) or AV Foundation AVCaptureSession and related classes (on iOS 4).